# AngularJS ctrl.$isEmpty returns value instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, is-empty

In an attempt to debug an issue with angular's required directive, I have duplicated the functionality myself:

```
.directive("myRequired", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.myRequired = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      ctrl.$validators.myRequired = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !attr.myRequired || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
      };

      attr.$observe('myRequired', function() {
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  };
})
```

I am using this directive on an `md-select` input with the following options:

```
$scope.options = [
        { name: "option1", id: 1 },
        { name: "option2", id: 2 },
        { name: "option3", id: 3 }
    ];
```

When my model has a pre populated value for my select, like so:

`$scope.myModel = {mySelect: 1};`

then the `myRequired` directive fails because `ctrl.$isEmpty()` returns the `viewValue` (i.e. `1`, `2`, or `3`) instead of `true`.

Why is it doing this?

How do I get it to return a boolean?

Comment: This is weird since `$isEmpty` [always returns a boolean](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c8d349870812284a82896087c05c2d19c8f5cdfd/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L363).Can you post a plunker to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If you have a pre-populated value for your select, what behavior are you expecting? It seems to me validation should succeed because there is a value present. Does validation not succeed?

Comment: correct, validation fails

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$isEmpty

`$isEmpty` will return `true` only if the value is one of `undefined`, '', `null` or `NaN`